# API to get call logs from an AVAYA phone server

Tags: avaya

Can someone help me understand how to get the call logs (calls actually made) on a AVAYA phone server? The documentation for this product is the worst and help online is almost nil.

I am able to telnet in and can do "list agent" and "list skill" among others but I do not see any command to actually list the calls made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command to show you the CDR (Call Detail Records) data. BUT, you can access the CDR data by doing the following:

In your PBX, run these commands:

```
change system-parameters cdr
```

Then set the option for "Enable CDR Stroage on Disk?" to y

You can now access the CDR by FTP'ing to your PBX and navigating to:
/var/home/ftp/CDR